# How modify the properties of the shadow hand?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm Working with the shadow hand, i'm moving it on gazebo by a glove with sensors, and that's works very nice, the little problem is that sometimes the shadow hand falls , supposed to be all the gravity and properties that are simulated in gazebo. If the gravity was desactivaded nothing works fine.

The only option i suppose have to be  change is the mass of the forearm and maybe put it more heavy. Also i need the position of the hand Kind different.
Obviously the pkg is restricted and changes don't very easy. and try to move it to other place is hard..

any idea??
thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49247/how-modify-the-properties-of-the-shadow-hand?/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also spawn it with the arm (roslaunch sr_hand gazebo_arm_and_hand.launch). The arm is attached to a desk which is very stable.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1